# Inverted Array (Read from the lowermost index)

Tags: arrays, vba

Will it be different if we reverse the initial value and last value of an array?

`For Each cel1 In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(27, 13), Cells(11, 13))`

`For Each cel1 In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(11, 13), Cells(27, 13))`

For the first case, will the first value appear shown as cells(27,13) rather than cells(11,13)?

These are my complete code:

`Sub arr_reverse()`

```
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim cel1 As Range
Dim tank_name() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = 16


i = n
j = 19

ReDim tank_name(i)
For Each cel1 In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(n, 13), Cells(11, 13))
    
    tank_name(i) = cel1.Value
    Cells(11, j) = tank_name(i)
    
    i = i - 1
    j = j + 1
    
    ReDim Preserve tank_name(i)
Next cel1
```

End Sub`

With these codes, the output of the array still read from the smallest index rather than the determined one at 'for' lines

Can you help me to make the array to read from the last index (or at least show the value of the last index first as the output)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, please forgot about i,j,k and n, about tank_name. Do you want copy cells value? So work with cells only:

```
Sub arr_reverse()
Dim oCell As Range, oTargetCell As Range
    Set oCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(27, 13)   ' Last cell in your range M11:M27
    Set oTargetCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 19) ' Your j = 19  column S
    While oCell.Row >= 11    ' Row of first cell
        oTargetCell = oCell
        Set oCell = oCell.Offset(-1, 0) ' Move Up
        Set oTargetCell = oTargetCell.Offset(0, 1) ' Move to right
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range`'s are stored as collections, and, when the collection is made, Excel reads from left to right, top to bottom, so the order is always the same.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/returning-an-object-from-a-collection-excel

To do want you want to do, use a `For..Next` loop with `Step -1`.

```
For k = 27 to 11 Step -1
cel = Cells(k, 13)
'code
Next k
```

Note `Dim i, j, k As Integer` only `Dim`'s `k` as Integer, `i` and `j` are declared as Variant types.

Write:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
```

instead.